# output from readlines() into a list

Tags: python3

I am stuck on this one and I am sure the answer is a simple one. I am new to python and am learning my way around.

I am working on a small project that needs to look at content of all .csv files in a directory. I have a python script in the same directory as follows;

```
import glob

path = '*.csv'   
files=glob.glob(path)   
for file in files:     
    f=open(file, 'r')
    print ('%s' % f.readlines())
```

This returns the data I need to the terminal, but I can not manage to get the data into a list. I need data in the list so I can compare data against other variables and take action on it.

For context, each .csv file contains 2 columns: "ID" and "Datetime".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, this is not the right place to ask questions about programming. You should consider [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Second, do you want to store the data from all the files in one list or do you want to store each file's data in a list apart?

Comment: Can you please clarify how do you expect data to be loaded into a list ?  For example, do you want `['line 1,another column\n','line 2,another column\n']`  or something like  `['line 1','another column']`?

Comment: Apologies for not providing specifics on the output I need, and I will take my queries to Stack Overflow. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import glob
path = '*.csv'   
files=glob.glob(path)   
output=[]
for file in files:     
    with open(file) as f:
        lines=f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            output.append(line)
```

Then, you can print the list to check the output

```
print(output)
```